# Hide loading bar on no .HTML file found

Tags: javascript, loading

I have the code below to find the next sequential page number and load it at the bottom of the page once the user hits the bottom of the screen.

the loading div slides down and as it is loading and up once it is done... it is set to "display:none" by default

What i need is a line of code in there which basically hides the #loading div if no more pages can be found to load... "  var url = "page"+nextpage+".html";" finds the new page... titled 'page 2.html, page3.html' and so on.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm assuming it is easy but I can't find a solution anywhere...

```
alreadyloading = false;
nextpage = 2;

$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    if (alreadyloading == false) {
        $("#loading").slideDown();
        var url = "page"+nextpage+".html";
        alreadyloading = true;

        $.post(url, function(data) {
            $('#newcontent').children().last().after(data);
            alreadyloading = false;
            nextpage++;
            $("#loading").slideUp();
        });

    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no such file then the AJAX request will fail, so you can do what you need from inside a "failure" handler. To be able to specify that, you one solution is to move from using `$.post` to using the more configurable `$.ajax`, which gives you all the necessary options:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#newcontent').children().last().after(data);
        nextpage++;
    },
    complete: function() {
        alreadyloading = false;
        $("#loading").slideUp();
    }
});
```

The `complete` callback contains code which will be executed no matter what happens with the request; the `success` callback will be executed before `complete`, but only if the request was successful.

Comment: `jQuery.post` does return the jqXHR object which allows you to bind error handlers using `fail()`.

Comment: @Matt: It seems that the jqXHR object also provides a `complete` method on itself which can be used to achieve the same effect. I don't think that any of those approaches are different enough to merit specific mention though.

Comment: Would I need to add that the #loading would slide down above 'complete:' to initiate the 'loading feedback' for the user?
Would this go in place of my current code? 
Thank you for the help!

Comment: @JByrne: `#loading` would slide down before the `$.ajax` call, just as in your existing code.

Comment: Thank you, It has almost worked. Now the #loading div slides up and down twice when you touch the bottom of the screen if there is no content to load?

Comment: @Jon: Thanks for the help, I managed to use the error: function(){ to tell the div to .hide() which worked.